Update data with laravel
The problem arises when I use the "save" method to save the data, as it returns as undefined, this is the code :
public function profile()
{
    return view('profile.edit', ['user' => Auth::user()]);
}

public function update(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'fullName' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users,email,' . Auth::id(),
        'image' => 'nullable|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);

    $user = Auth::user();
    $user->name = $request->input('fullName');
    $user->email = $request->input('email');

    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        if ($user->image) {
            Storage::delete('public/profile_images/' . $user->image);
        }
        $imageName = time() . '.' . $request->image->extension();
        $request->image->storeAs('public/profile_images', $imageName);
        $user->image = $imageName;
    }

    $user->save(); // it gives me undefined

    return redirect()->route('profile.edit')->with('success', 'Profile updated successfully.');
}

public function updatePassword(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'currentPassword' => 'required',
        'newPassword' => 'required|string|min:8|confirmed',
    ]);

    $user = Auth::user();

    if (!Hash::check($request->input('currentPassword'), $user->password)) {
        return back()->withErrors(['currentPassword' => 'Current password is incorrect']);
    }

    $user->password = Hash::make($request->input('newPassword'));
    $user->save(); // it gives me undefined

    return redirect()->route('profile.edit')->with('success', 'Password changed successfully.');
}


I make sure that I'm using the Auth::user() object correctly.
Ensure that the form correctly sends data to the appropriate controller and that the image field is configured properly for file uploads.
Ensure that the User model utilizes Eloquent traits correctly and that the configuration is accurate.


What do you mean by undefined ?

This statement // $user = Auth::user(); // is bad.
So suggest that statement.
use App\Models\User;
...
$user = new User();

Check if this path were included in your controller
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

Try dd($user) to see your user data
Or you might as well update the data using your email since it's unique value;
$user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();


The issue you're facing is likely due to the way you're interacting with the User model in Laravel. The $user->save() method should not return undefined in PHP. Instead, it should return a boolean value indicating whether the save operation was successful or not.
Here are a few things you can try to resolve the issue:
Check if the User model is set up correctly:
Ensure that your User model extends the Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User class or the appropriate base model class for your application. Additionally, make sure that the model includes the necessary traits, such as Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable and Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\Asll if you're using any casts.
Verify the database connection:
Ensure that your application can connect to the database correctly. Check your database configuration in the .env file or the config/database.php file.
